# ViewModel: Callback onChanged - does not show changed values after integer 19 until value drops back below 19

Tags: android, callback, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have an activity that is supposed to display a temperature and it does, up to 19 (in centigrade). Once the number exceeds 19 there is no update. I put a log.i trace and I can see the value being updated into LiveData, but the onChange stops catching the change after 19 and the Log.i also does not record the output. Is the a reason why 19 is the magical number, but more importantly how would I correct the issue? I tried using a number fields but get the same results. The field is in activity_main.xml and is an EditText  I have a limited amount of Android experience. Thank you in advance.

```
MainViewModel mainViewModel;
private TextView editText;

    mainViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    mainViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<CharSequence>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(CharSequence charSequence) {
            editText.setText(charSequence);
            Log.i(DBGTAG, "TEMPER" + charSequence);
        }
    });
```

MainViewModel.java

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {
private final MutableLiveData<CharSequence> text = new MutableLiveData<>();

public void setText(CharSequence input){
    text.setValue(input);
}
public MutableLiveData<CharSequence> getText(CharSequence input){
    return text;
}
public LiveData<CharSequence> getText(){
    return text;
}
}
```

where LiveData is being updated

```
 UserDynamics.txTemperature = temperatureValue;                                      
 editText.setText(temperatureValue);
 mainViewModel.setText(temperatureValue);
```

tried both methods, same result

Comment: i don't think there is any magic number. Livedata will be observed when there is a change.  where are you updating livedata from?

Comment: It is being updated as above, in the MainActivity, or "where LiveData is being updated" as listed above

Comment: it should work. where do you update from which method of activity class. is it done in any callback?